# How to Send ParseObject via intent, and retrieve it from the new activity?

Tags: android

I want to save the time of running query again on the DB, and to keep the parseObject, and to send it via intent to another activity which will handle it according to some logic.

I found this: https://gist.github.com/jamiechapman/5375115
which helps me to send it via intent, but there is no way there to get back the ParseObject.

Any idea?

Comment: You would need to get your classes to implement `Parcelable`

Comment: Which classes? Lets say Activity1 calls Activity via intent.

Comment: Which classes? Lets say Activity1 calls Activity via intent. both oof them need to implement it? and how I should use it then?

Comment: The ParseObject class